# If there is a expected value in the table then I want to select the hyperlink that exists in 0th index of the row using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a table in my webpage as attached in the diagram attached. I want to select the Hyperlink existing in 0th index of the table row if my expected value is there in that particular row.

How can I implement this in Selenium WebDriver using Java? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBqal.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code for the same:

```
List <WebElement> rowElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("\\table\\tr"));

for(int i=1; i< rowElements.size(); i++){

     List <WebElement> colElements = rowElements.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));

  for(int j=1; j<colElements.getSize(); j++){ 

   if(colElements.get(j).getText().equals("yourValue")){ //yourValue is value to be matched in column 3

      colElements.get(0).click();

    //clicking the hyperlink

   }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use XPATH to achieve this. We need to locate the "value3" cell(thuw finding row) in the table from and then keeping it has reference we need to navigate to the first column.

Step 1: locating the Value row.

```
".//td[contains(text(),"'+value+'")]" //Where Value is the "value3" that you know,
```

Step 2: Now keeping step 1 as reference navigate back to the first column using "preceeding".

```
".//td[contains(text(),"'+value+'")]/preceding-sibling::td[3]"//Navigating back to the first column
```

The final code should look similar to this.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[contains(text(),"'+value+'")]/preceding-sibling::td[3]")).click();
```