# Find element which have common class name and label id- selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

There is a table in the web page for which we have to scroll table to get data into view. All the element have same class name and Id how to find out specific element which has a different name

Comment: check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44225714/if-there-is-a-expected-value-in-the-table-then-i-want-to-select-the-hyperlink-th/44228217#44228217

Comment: You need to write the xpath accordingly. I can help you if you can provide the DOM